# Error in protobuf-dt

Tags: java, eclipse, protobuf-dt

I'm using Eclipse with the protobuf-dt plugin. I've set up a project and whenever I edit a proto file the following error appears in the logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ImportRootsProtocOption.locationAsFile(ImportRootsProtocOption.java:94)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ImportRootsProtocOption.singleImportRoot(ImportRootsProtocOption.java:77)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ImportRootsProtocOption.initialize(ImportRootsProtocOption.java:58)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ImportRootsProtocOption.addOptionToCommand(ImportRootsProtocOption.java:42)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ProtocCommandBuilder.buildCommand(ProtocCommandBuilder.java:51)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.builder.protoc.ProtobufBuildParticipant.build(ProtobufBuildParticipant.java:79)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:161)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:69)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:291)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.fullBuild(XtextBuilder.java:319)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:155)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I did some digging in the code and it seemed to be trying to resolve the import paths and failing so I tried changing the config as follows (previously the one directory option was selected):
[image]

The error changed to:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ProtocCommand.setFileToCompile(ProtocCommand.java:42)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.protoc.command.ProtocCommandBuilder.buildCommand(ProtocCommandBuilder.java:55)
at com.google.eclipse.protobuf.ui.builder.protoc.ProtobufBuildParticipant.build(ProtobufBuildParticipant.java:79)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:161)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:69)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:291)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.fullBuild(XtextBuilder.java:319)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:155)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and how I fix it?

Comment: You might comment on the protobuf-dt GitHub issue here: https://github.com/google/protobuf-dt/issues/20

Comment: @howlger Good idea thanks, I've done that.